# How to limit imap search/uid fetches

Tags: python, imap

In order to avoid

```
imaplib.error: command: UID => got more than 10000 bytes
```

I would like to fetch only a specific number of mails or requesting the number of search matches, without throwing an exception.

Is the only way how i can handle this problem, reducing the `SINCE` `BEFORE` interval on every exception, until i reach the first or last mail?

[Editing _MAXLINE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25457441/reading-emails-with-imaplib-got-more-than-10000-bytes-error) would only affect my environment and isn't helpful in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only solution is to reduce SINCE/BEFORE, or its equivalent.

Will you submit a patch for python's imaplib, or shall I? We can't leave this forever.

Comment: The next versions of python should be much more generous. The change has just been committed on the 2.7.x, 3.4.x and 3.5-to-be branches.